# Cannot install SPFX package using Site Scripts

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, site-design, site-script

We've noticed that for starting from July 19 2019, we can no longer install SPFX packages using [Site Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview). Here is the very minimum sample that replicates the issue:

**siteDesign.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "schema.json",
    "actions": [
        {
            "verb": "installSolution",
            "id": "{AppPackageId:ContosoCentral}"
        }        
    ],
    "version": 1
  }
```

**Error message:**

[image]

SPFX package is deployed to the App Catalog with no errors:

[image]

Installing the SPFX app without Site Designs works perfectly fine:

[image]

**Questions**

- Does anyone have the same issue? Please, reply in comments.
- **Main question**: Is there a workaround for this? Anything we can do to solve it?
- Is there a way to get more information about the error? `Install SPFX Solution: Something went wrong and we could not complete this action` sounds awefully unhelpful.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

I've found related issue in GitHub: [Cannot Install SPFx Solution or Activate Custom Feature using a Site Design #3543](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3543), but I don't see any resolutions.

**Update 2. Quick replication steps**

You can try to replicate it by using any SPFX package:

- Install SPFx package to the App Catalog. Let's call it "ContosoApp".
- Run the following PnP script to add a new site design

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/CommunicationSite 
Add-PnPSiteScript -Title "Sample-Site-Script" -Description "Sample Site Script that demonstrates an issue" -Content "{ `"$schema`": `"schema.json`", `"actions`": [ { `"verb`": `"installSolution`", `"id`": `"{AppPackageId:ContosoApp}`" } ], `"version`": 1 }`""
$siteScript = Get-PnPSiteScript | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Sample-Site-Script"}
Add-PnPSiteDesign -Title "Sample-Site-Design" -Description "Sample Site Design that demonstrates an issue" -SiteScriptIds $siteScript.Id -WebTemplate CommunicationSite
```

- Apply site Design to the site via the UI:
  [image]

Comment: in the `"id": "{AppPackageId:ContosoCentral}"`, i have used the product id of the SPFx package. Are you using the same ?? I got the product id by executing the `Get-PnPApp` command and replaced it in the site design. It works at my end :)